# How to pass user input variable from a python GUI as argument to another python code

Tags: python, bash

I am an novice in GUI development using python. In a recent code i am working on I need to pass an input variable from an python GUI i have made and the value is needed to be sent to another python code running separately via an argument. I am having an make.sh file with contents as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter participants Name:"
read name 

echo "Please enter participant's Age: "
read age 

echo "Please enter participant's Gender:(M/F) "
read sex 


python -W ignore test.py $name
clear

read -n 1 -s -p "Press any key to continue"
python -W ignore test2.py $name $age $sex
clear
```

How can I implement this using python GUI.

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import os
    import subprocess

    top = Tk()

    L2 = Label(top, text="Enter Participate name")
    L2.config(font=("Times", 11))
    L2.grid(row = 5, column = 4)

    userName = StringVar()

    U1 = Entry(top, width=30, textvariable=userName)
    U1.grid(row = 5, column = 10)

    L3 = Label(top, text="Enter Age")
    L3.config(font=("Times", 11))
    L3.grid(row = 7, column = 4)

    userName2 = IntVar()

    U2 = Entry(top, width=30, textvariable=userName2)
    U2.grid(row = 7, column = 10)

    L4 = Label(top, text="Enter Gender:(M/F)")
    L4.config(font=("Times", 11))
    L4.grid(row = 9, column = 4)

    userName3 = StringVar()

    U3 = Entry(top, width=30, textvariable=userName3)
    U3.grid(row = 9, column = 10)

    def source():

        subprocess.call("python test.py userName.get()", shell=True)
        subprocess.call("python test2.py userName.get()", shell=True)

    B1 = Button(top, text="Submit", fg="blue", command=source)
    B1.grid(row = 20, column=5)

    top.mainloop()
```

This is a code i have written. I am also getting an error while running this code.

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Comment: You're calling the program with the following command line : `python test.py userName.get()`  but you want to append the return value instead: `.call("python test.py " + userName.get())` . I find it often helps to print out commands before handing them to the shell: `cmd = "python test.py userName.get()" : print cmd : subprocess.call(cmd) `

Comment: Thank you Corion, I tried this as you have said, but after execution of the same, the programme is still returning the same error as output.